# NSTimer callback on background thread

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have a `NSTimer` defined as follows:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(fooBar)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

I want it to call the call back function `fooBar` in this case using a background thread. But when I check with `if ([NSThread mainThread])` i'm *always* getting it on the main thread. Is there any other way aside from dispatching a thread from the callback function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the timer to main thread. Your call back will also be in main thread. To schedule the timer in a background thread, I think you need to use NSOperation subclass and schedule the timer to [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] from inside the operation's *main* method.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BackgroundTimer : NSOperation
{
    BOOL _done;
}
@end



#import "BackgroundTimer.h"

@implementation BackgroundTimer

-(void) main
{
    if ([self isCancelled])
    {
        return;
    }

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(fooBar)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

    //keep the runloop going as long as needed
    while (!_done && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                              beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);

}

@end
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you also need to keep the runloop going inside your operation's start method as long as you need it. Otherwise, the thread will die immediately and the timer won't fire. You need to have a condition that will exit the runloop. That condition may be triggered during one of your timer calls.

Comment: Is there an example of this anywhere?

Comment: I will post an example over the weekend.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a timer on a background thread, the most efficient way to do that is with a dispatch timer:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_source_t timer;
```

and you can then configure this timer to fire every two seconds:

```
- (void)startTimer {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.app.timer", 0);
    self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), 2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{
        // call whatever you want here
    });
    dispatch_resume(self.timer);
}

- (void)stopTimer {
    dispatch_cancel(self.timer);
    self.timer = nil;
}
```